# Ionic Cap/Angular App - Android Build fails while using Capacitor-plugin-playlist

Tags: android, ionic-framework, android-mediaplayer, hybrid-mobile-app, capacitor-plugin

I understand this issue is a bit niche but I am hoping someone within Ionic community is able to give me an insight on this. Or if anyone has already implemented this plugin https://github.com/phiamo/capacitor-plugin-playlist on their project.

I have followed all the instructions as provided in the repo but still facing build issue only in Android.

FAILURE: Build completed with 8 failures.

### 1: Task failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugAarMetadata'.
  `> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.

  > Could not find com.devbrackets.android:exomedia:4.3.0.
  > Searched in the following locations:
  > - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/devbrackets/android/exomedia/4.3.0/exomedia-4.3.0.pom
  > - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/devbrackets/android/exomedia/4.3.0/exomedia-4.3.0.pom
  > - file:/path//android/capacitor-cordova-android-plugins/src/main/libs/exomedia-4.3.0.jar
  > - file:/path//android/capacitor-cordova-android-plugins/src/main/libs/exomedia.jar
  > - file:/path//android/app/libs/exomedia-4.3.0.jar
  > - file:/path//android/app/libs/exomedia.jar
  > Required by:
  > project :app > project :capacitor-plugin-playlist
  > Could not find com.google.android.exoplayer:extension-okhttp:2.9.6.
  > Searched in the following locations:
  > - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/google/android/exoplayer/extension-okhttp/2.9.6/extension-okhttp-2.9.6.pom
  > - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/google/android/exoplayer/extension-okhttp/2.9.6/extension-okhttp-2.9.6.pom
  > - file:/path//android/capacitor-cordova-android-plugins/src/main/libs/extension-okhttp-2.9.6.jar
  > - file:/path//android/capacitor-cordova-android-plugins/src/main/libs/extension-okhttp.jar
  > - file:/path//android/app/libs/extension-okhttp-2.9.6.jar
  > - file:/path//android/app/libs/extension-okhttp.jar
  > Required by:
  > project :app > project :capacitor-plugin-playlist
  > Could not find com.devbrackets.android:playlistcore:2.0.1.
  > Searched in the following locations:
  > - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/devbrackets/android/playlistcore/2.0.1/playlistcore-2.0.1.pom
  > - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/devbrackets/android/playlistcore/2.0.1/playlistcore-2.0.1.pom
  > - file:/path//android/capacitor-cordova-android-plugins/src/main/libs/playlistcore-2.0.1.jar
  > - file:/path//android/capacitor-cordova-android-plugins/src/main/libs/playlistcore.jar
  > - file:/path//android/app/libs/playlistcore-2.0.1.jar
  > - file:/path//android/app/libs/playlistcore.jar
  > Required by:
  > project :app > project :capacitor-plugin-playlist`
- Try:

> ## Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

I have already tried adding adding different versions of these dependencies in app level build.gradle
`implementation 'com.devbrackets.android:exomedia:4.2.3'   implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:extension-okhttp:2.11.1'   implementation 'com.devbrackets.android:playlistcore:2.1.0'`
Also I have already checked and tried modifying android directory level build gradle  to this:

`repositories {         google()         mavenCentral()       jcenter()       maven { url 'https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2' }      }`

Comment: What capacitor version are you on?

Comment: Appreicate your reply, I've actually resolved this issue. I just had to add jcenter() in build.gradle file